# Multiple subscriptions to the same Meteor Collection

Tags: meteor

#### Goal

I have a top-level Collection named `Players` and a Session variable called 'n'.  In addition to my top-level Collection, I'd like to have a Collection of the top-'n' `Players` based on `player.points`, which updates in reaction to `Session.set('n', n)` (and, of course, any changing of the underlying `Players` data).

#### Rationale

The reason I would like a `TopNPlayers` is because within each player template (call it `Template.player_item`) I want to provide a couple of variables:

- `Template.player_item.isInTopN`, which sets a CSS class to highlight a player if it's in the top-'n' in points
- `Template.player_item.PointsVsBaseline`, which gives the difference between that player's points and the 'n'th player in `TopNPlayers`.

Since I don't want to manually manage a global variable containing `Players` filtered by the value of `Session.get('n')`, and I certainly don't want to calculate the top-'n' every time I render another `player_item`, I'd like to set up an additional subscription to the `Players` Collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you need a separate collection, wouldn't a cursor do the trick?

Something like:

```
var topNPlayers = function() { 
  return Players.find({}, {limit: Session.get('n')}); 
}

Template.player_item.isInTopN = function() {

  // there are a bunch of ways you could do this step...
  _.include(topNPlayers().fetch(), this);
}
```

Comment: You'd also need your cursor to sort by points so that limiting would get the right players.

Comment: Hi Tom.  Thanks for your answer.  I guess I'm wondering:  1) does your var `topNPlayers` respond automatically if `Players` changes and 2) does it need to be recalculated for each `player_item` when rendering the collection view?

Comment: Jimmy: 1) Yes. 2) It will, although minimongo is in-memory client-side so it may not be a big performance hit. An optimization would be to use a `Meteor.deps.Context` to create a reactive session variable of the required score to be in the topN.